# Docker Traefik and letsencrypt wildcard

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik

I've been trying to get traefik to install wildcard cert on my domain which requires dns challenge
from reading the logs it seems it was able to actually issue the cert but not install them correctly

```
time="2018-04-07T19:10:35Z" level=debug msg="Unable to marshal provider conf *acme.Provider with error: json: unsupported type: chan *acme.StoredData"
legolog: 2018/04/07 19:10:57 [INFO][example.tld] The server validated our request
legolog: 2018/04/07 19:10:58 [INFO][*.example.tld] acme: Validations succeeded; requesting certificates
legolog: 2018/04/07 19:11:01 [INFO][*.example.tld] Server responded with a certificate.
time="2018-04-07T19:11:01Z" level=error msg="Error loading new configuration, aborted unable to generate TLS certificate : tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
time="2018-04-07T19:12:33Z" level=debug msg="http2: server: error reading preface from client ******omitted***: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority"
```

my domain dns provider is cloudflare

here's my docker docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.6.0-rc4
    command: --api --docker
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    environment:
      - CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=admin@example.tld
      - CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

And my traefik.toml

```
debug = true

logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "example.tld"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[acme]
email = "admin@example.tld"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
acmeLogging = true
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0

[[acme.domains]]
   main = "example.tld"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "*.example.tld"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue, it's a mistake on my part.

in the traefik.toml
you cannot use `OnHostRule = true` for wildcards certs

ReadMore:
docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#onhostrule

Comment: your link is dead, i think this is the new live doc: https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#onhostrule